# How to add/remove a row without affecting formula in a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column B with a formula full of IFs with each cell referenced to the cell above it.
From time to time, I need to delete some rows. Once a row is deleted, the formula in column B gives #REF for the remaining cells beneath the deleted row.
How can I delete a row and the formula is automatically updated by referencing the new cell above it?
Also, when adding a row, can the formula automatically take place in cell B without me adding it each time?

Comment: `INDIRECT` is the needed function.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your situation and layout really. Depending on that, there are 2 options.

Commented out You could use absolute references which I think is what you want, such as

```
=IF($A$1)
```

The $ means it sticks to that cell, what ever the value!

However, depending on what your deleting, you may find the use of Indirect useful

> Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents. Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself.

```
=INDIRECT($A$2)
```

[image]

More [information and quote and image source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem earlier. This is how I referenced the cell above the current one (A2 in this case):

```
=OFFSET(A2,-1,0)
```

However, when adding rows, formula needs to be copied and pasted. Unless, a script is created to do that automatically.

For more information on offset formula: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66

Comment: The `INDIRECT` function is a better solution.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on how 'INDIRECT' function can be used in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I have a workbook with worksheets drawing data via formulae from another worksheet. The nature of the data means that there can be numerous rows with either duplicate or erroneous data that need removing. Deleting rows in the source worksheet upsets the import and calculations. I use an editing workaround as I go through cleansing the data. The process is simple. I create an Edit data worksheet. Copy the entire worksheet of the source data into it. Edit the data, deleting rows as required, then pasting the data back onto the source worksheet. Simple and highly effective!